# Slick slider not working in vue components

Tags: javascript, slider, vuejs2

I am trying to use the [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in a .vue component but I get an error.

> .slick is not a function

I have made all the setup requirements. This is the code am using:

```
    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        slider: null
    },
    methods: {
        selectImage: function () {
            //http call here
            return images
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.slider = $('.gallery').slick({
            animation: true
        });
    }
});

<div class='gallery'>
  <div v-for="img in images" @click="selectImage(img)">
    <img v-bind:src="img.url">
  </div>
</div>
```

My phpstorm does not allow ES6 and am suspecting that it might be the issue.

Here is a fiddle with my code: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfbysyx5/)

Comment: I hope this is the last carousel you'll ever need :P Possible to create a fiddle of it?

Comment: I used the foundation orbit but it does not work with dynamically loaded images using `v-for`.  Looking for a slider that does is a nightmare

Comment: Have you added this line in your HTML/index.html: `<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes. I have. I have also added the `slick.css` file

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/hyxsusjf/) is an implementation of carousel with bootstrap for your reference and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/simeydotme/fmo50w7n/) is for slick, Can you please create a fiddle for your code, which can help people answer here your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/tfbysyx5/4/).

I am not getting the error you are getting. However it was not working earlier as the code: `$('.gallery').slick({` was defined in mount block, but given that you are getting the data in async way, I have moved this to `updated` block which will be executed after your data is updated.

Following is working vue code:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#gallery",
  data: function() {
    return {
      images: [],
      slider: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    var that = this
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.images.push('http://devcereal.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/URL-URI-URN-whats-difference.png')
      that.images.push('http://www.shawacademy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/URL-1000x605.jpg')

    }, 300)
  },
  updated () {
        $('.gallery').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        dots: true,
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 500,
          settings: {
            dots: false,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        }]
      });
  }
})
```

Comment: @PhillisPeters Than there is some issue in your code, it may be not loading `slick.js` properly.

Comment: It did not load the `slick.js` when I used `bower components` and add the script tag in my page so I used `npm` to install slick, added the css files to my `gulpfile` and now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Saurabh your solution helped me run slick but there is one more problem i have and it is that the navigation arrows are not showing at their proper position. so can you help me find out the issue

Comment: @Saurabh, Seems I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255934/why-the-slider-does-not-work-when-i-click-another-tab-on-vue-component