# Why the slider does not work when I click another tab on vue component?

Tags: vue.js, slider, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My view like this :

```
@foreach($leagues as $league)
    <a data-toggle="tab" @click="$refs.leagues.changeLeague({{ $league->id }})">
        {{ $league->name }}
    </a>
@endforeach
...
<div class="tab-pane active">
    <top-league class="slick" league-id="{{ $league_id }}" ref="leagues"></top-league>
</div>
```

My top league component vue like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="item in items">
             <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-image">
                    <a :href="baseUrl+'/leagues/'+item.id+'/'+item.name"
                        :style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + baseUrl + '/img/leagues/'+item.photo+ ')'}">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        props: ['leagueId'],
        mounted(){
            setTimeout( function(){  
                $('.slick').not('.slick-initialized').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});
            }  , 10000 );
        },
        created() {
            this.getTopLeague([{league_id: this.leagueId}]) // this is ajax if load first
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'getListLeague'
            ]),
            items() {
                const n = ['getListLeague']
                return this[n[0]] // this is response ajax // exist 5 league
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions([
                'getTopLeague'
            ]),
            changeLeague(leagueId) {
                this.getTopLeague([{league_id: leagueId}]) // this is ajax if a link clicked     
                setTimeout( function(){
                    $('.slick').not('.slick-initialized').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});
                    console.log('test')
                }  , 10000 );
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When loaded the first time, there are 5 items of data displayed in the form of sliders. And the slider works. But if I click the another tab. For example I click League B, the slider not works. Whereas the result of console.log('test') had run

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you getting correct `leagueId`, Can you create a dummy fiddle reproducing it?

Comment: @Saurabh, Yes, I getting leagueId correctly. The problem is if I click another tab, the slider not work

Comment: Can you create a dummy fiddle reproducing it?

Comment: @Saurabh, Such a bit difficult. Because I combine between view blade laravel and vue component